# como puedo hacer para que el usuario ingrese un dato con una extensión al final refiriendose a una unidad de medida?

Tags: python

a lo que me refiero es a que el usuario ingrese por ejemplo "50m" (la m refiriéndose a metros) y que el programa me lo reconozca como 5000 centímetros

este es mi programa:

```
if calcular == "velocidad":
    print("\n-----Calculando velocidad-----")
    distancia = input("Ingrese la distancia: ")
    distancia = comprobar_numero(distancia)

    tiempo = input("Ingrese el tiempo: ")
    tiempo = comprobar_numero(tiempo)

    velocidad = float(distancia) / float(tiempo)
    print("La velociada es", velocidad, "\n")
```

Comment: recibe dos datos: el número en una variable y la unidad en otra. Luego, haz conversiones

Comment: podrias leer una linea con `input` y luego usar una [expresión regular](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/re.html) para procesarla

Comment: Puedes crear una lista con las unidades de medida disponibles, asi no ingrese una unidad que no quieras

Answer (score 5):

Además de las soluciones que puedas programar por ti mismo (leer la entrada como una cadena para después separar los números de las unidades, usando por ejemplo expresiones regulares), quizás te interese saber que hay una biblioteca muy potente que ya sabe hacer estas cosas y hasta convertir entre diferentes unidades. Se trata de [pint](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Una vez la tengas instalada puedes hacer simplemente:

```
from pint import UnitRegistry

ur = UnitRegistry()

distancia = ur(input("Distancia? "))
tiempo = ur(input("Tiempo? "))

velocidad = distancia/tiempo

print("Velocidad =", velocidad, "=", velocidad.to("km/hr"))
```

Que al ejecutarse funcionaría así:

```
Distancia? 300cm
Tiempo? 2s
Velocidad = 150.0 centimeter / second = 5.4 kilometer / hour
```

Un inconveniente, como puedes ver, es que las unidades aparecen en inglés (y deben ser introducidas también en inglés por el usuario, a menos que use abreviaturas como `cm` que son independientes del idioma).

Puedes forzar a que lo que se imprime use también abreviaturas, para que así no se note que está en inglés. Para ello usa el formato `{:~}` como por ejemplo así:

```
print("Velocidad = {:~} = {:~}".format(velocidad, velocidad.to("km/hr")))
```

que imprimiría en el ejemplo anterior:

```
Velocidad = 150.0 cm / s = 5.4 km / hr
```

Con un poco de esfuerzo se podría adaptar para que los nombres de las unidades (sin abreviar) estén en español. Habría que reescribir un archivo de texto que le acompaña en el que están definidas todas las unidades que puede manejar (son muchas pues soporta muchas magnitudes físicas, dicho archivo de configuración tiene más de 800 líneas!)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se me ocurre si no quieres usar regex es: declara en una lista tus unidades de medida, por ejemplo:

```
medidasList= [c, m, k]
```

Después recibe el input y sepáralo en una lista, y posteriormente toma el último elemento.

```
resp = input(‘Ingresa una cantidad en cm o m o km’)
```

(Aquí el usuario tendría que poner por ejemplo 1c para 1cm, o 1m para un metro).

```
cantidadList = resp.split()  #separamos por elemento
```

Último elemento:

```
x = cantidadList[len(cantidadList)-1]
cantidad= cantidadList[:len(cantidadList)-2]
```

Así obtienes el último dígito (x) y la cantidad(cantidad). Después solo haz un:

```
cantidad = “”.join(cantidad)
```

Aquí ya tienes la cadena que contiene la cantidad en la variable `cantidad` y tienes por separado la unidad de medida en la variable `x`. Solo convierte la cantidad a float o int y haz algunas sentencias if para ver si x es igual a c, m o k y de acuerdo a cada caso multiplica por 1, 100 o 100000